# MySQL Trigger on 2 tables with

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have 2 tables

FIRST

```
 ps_product (id_product, price)
```

SECOND

```
 ps_product_price (id_product, price, price_tax)
```

Now what I trying to do is to SET TRIGGER:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_ps_product_price_update`  
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `ps_product_price` 
      FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
      UPDATE ps_product 
       SET price = NEW.price_tax -(NEW.price_tax * 0.1666666666666666666)
       WHERE id_product = NEW.id_product;  
    END
```

When ps_rpoduct_price TABLE, COLUMN(price_tax) is updated then update TABLE ps_product, COLUMN (price)

And that works fine but when I try do do this same other way around:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_ps_product_update`  
    AFTER UPDATE ON `ps_product` 
      FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
      UPDATE ps_product_price
       SET price_tax = (NEW.price * 1.2)
       WHERE id_product = NEW.id_product;  
    END
```

Then I get an error:

> Can't update table 'ps_rpoduct' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: triggers cannot cause other triggers to be invoked. you'd get into an infinite loop situation and kill your DB.

Comment: *"Then i get ERROR:..."* --- Call it a "blessing in disguise" ;-)